# Wordpress: Set Featured Image meta box not available even its support is added

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been adding featured images to my post for a while back but after the installation of a plugin (I think) the **Set Featured Image** meta box disappeared from **Edit or Add New Post page** in **admin tab**. I've re-installed wordpress but I can't get that featured image box back.

I have also added support for it in my theme's functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

[image: Image for better understanding]
[image: Image of screen options]

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the top of the post page and click **Screen Options**. There should be a drop down with a lot of options like in the image attached. Make sure that **Featured Image** is selected.

[image]

Comment: I've added a picture of available options in `Screen Options` tab.

Comment: remove `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` from functions.php and let me know if it is still not there. What theme are you using?

Comment: I am making my own theme bro. When I use built-in themes like `twentyfifteen`, `twentyfourteen` or `twentythirteen`, it appears. I'll try removing that.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't appear even after I comment the line: `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`